# Blocking in java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to make a Stream block and wait for data to be ready in the data source and then I close it when I know there is nothing else to wait for? I already tried to make the data source a blocking one like `BlockingQueue` but it didn't work obviously as I am looping on the stream using `forEeach` not using `take` or `peek` functions that block.

Comment: Obviously any of the stream modifiers (e.g. map) that allow for a user-defined function will wait for that function to return its value before continuing. Not sure I understand what you're getting at here.

Comment: I'm not clear what it is you want to accomplish.  Do you want to iterate over the content in a streaming fashion, or take some explicit action when the consumer is empty?

Comment: It might be useful to share the code you are talking about. So we can understand what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Streams are designed around [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) as the ultimate source of their elements. You could implement the `tryAdvance()` method to test whether another element exists, blocking until the result is known.

You mentioned a `BlockingQueue`, which is useful in concurrent processing. If you are "producing" elements in some threads, and trying to "consume" them in others, you might find that a [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) fits your application better than a custom `Stream`.

`Spliterator` is a fairly simple interface in terms of its operations, but implementing it correctly requires a good understanding of [spliterator "characteristics".](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--) I would consider it an advanced topic, and while there are cases where a custom implementation is useful, it might also be a warning sign that you are looking at the wrong approach—you don't have to use `Stream` for everything.

(Create a `Stream` from a `Spliterator` with [`StreamSupport.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-).)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work:

```
BlockingQueue<T> queue = ...; // Signal with a null sentinel.
Iterable<T> collection = () -> new Iterator<T>() {
    private boolean hasCurrent;
    private T current;
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (!hasCurrent) {
            current = queue.take();
            hasCurrent = true;
        }
        return current != null;
    }
    public T next() {
        if (hasCurrent) {
            hasCurrent = false;
            return current;
        } else {
            return queue.take();
        }
    }
};
StreamSupport.stream(collection.spliterator(), false)...
```

There may well be better ways.